# Macro to generate a c++ header file using excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am thinking to make a excel file which can generate a headre file for my c++ source file. 
Previoulsy we used to generate .h files using excel but i dont know the logic behind that(Hope some macros using for that).

My header file contains this many data and my intention is to give "MYapp Alpha 0.0.3" through excel file because the version number changes for each release. If I used excel file then I can edit that excel and it creates .h file for me, later some more informations I can make configurable through excel file.

Is it possible to write macro that edit "MYapp Alpha 0.0.3" without touching other

```
 #define APP_FLASH_APP_ID 0x123
 #define APP_VERSION_NUM "MYapp Alpha 0.0.3 "
 #define APP_PRODUCT_NAME "TPI "
 #define APP_DESCRIPTION_STR APP_PRODUCT_NAME APP_VERSION_NUM
 #define APP_RELEASE_DATE_STR "10/11/13"
 #define APP_SOFTWARE_PARTNUM_LEN 10
```

Some valuable help or suggestions needed

Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

Well basically a .h file is a text file. So you need to do some string processing, open a text file, print the data in it and close it.

To open and close a text file use this:

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("D:\test.h")
oFile.WriteLine "tfadfadsest"
oFile.Close
Set fso = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you:

```
Sub test()

    Const strVerNumber As String = "0.0.4"

    Dim FS, TSsource
    Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set TSsource = FS.OpenTextFile("C:\test.txt", 1, 2)

    Dim tmpString As String
    tmpString = TSsource.ReadAll
    TSsource.Close

    tmpString = Replace(tmpString, _
                        "MYapp Alpha 0.0.3", _
                        "MYapp Alpha " & strVerNumber)

    Dim TSout
    Set TSout = FS.Createtextfile("C:\testOUT.txt", True)

    TSout.Write tmpString
    TSout.Close

End Sub
```

See these methods: [OpenTextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), [CreateTextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265018%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), [ReadAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265365%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and [Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265378%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about something like this:

Formulas:
[image: 1]

Results:
[image: 2]

Comment: you very well understood my need. I need exaxtly the same and need to copy in a fixed location say "c:/user/mydata"

My real need is to save it in 2 files one *.h and other *.opt. Both are fixed location